# why does this touchesBegan method code get trigger in my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, touches

Why does the touchesBegan method code get trigger in my UITableView?

Background:  I have a UITableView within a UINavigationController.  In the UITableView I have custom cells based on subclassing UITableViewCell.  I current don't have a selectRowAtIndexPath method in my UITableView.

Some aspects of the answer that would be good to cover off would include:

- why it doesn't work obviously
- in terms of getting it to work, how does get one ensure that the correct touch (single-tap) detection will not prevent the other scenarios to work like: selecting a table row, scrolling the tableview contents up and down etc.
- should the simulator be able to pick up touches etc, or are there cases here where you need the physical device

Code:

```
@interface AppointmentListController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> 
.
.
.

@implementation AppointmentListController
.
.
.

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        timeStampStart = event.timestamp;
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        NSTimeInterval timeStampEnd = event.timestamp;
        NSTimeInterval touchDuration = timeStampEnd - timeStampStart;

        if(touchDuration > 0.2)
            [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        else
            DLog(@" - TOUCH EVENT OCCURS");

        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to put up this as a possible answer, the answer being there is no relative straight way to achieve what I've asked for this. That is a way for a tap or double-tap to be detected in a UITableView page, which is already picking up row touches and scroll up/down etc.

Haven't verified whether this is the case or not, but people could up-vote this answer if they believe this to be true.